# Hide/Show Part of a Page in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have an image on my website. I would like when I click it, it show a `<div>`, and when I click it another time, it hides the `<div>`. 
How can I do this in JavaScript? Should I use jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this in JQuery:

```
<img id="img_id" src="image path here" />
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">Some content</div>

$('#img_id').toggle({ 
   function(){$('#mydiv').show();},
   function(){$('#mydiv').hide();}
});
```

First click on an element with id `img_id` will show an element with id `mydiv` and second click would hide it.

See more info about **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** function.

Comment: And, don't I have to link the image?

Comment: @Francesc: As can be seen the `img_id` is supposed to be for an image. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [jQuery API .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
- [jQuery API .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [jQuery API .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)